# Implementing Microsoft 365 Authentication and Fetching Tenant Secure Score in React Web App

Tags: reactjs

User
User
i want to create a web app as below
1 front page should have log in button , when users click on it, it should authenticate with microsoft 365 account from any tenant and login once user  is logged in it should automatically fetch that specific microsoft tenant secure score

I want detail code how do i do that